# MISO MOSI not moving in SPI

Tags: microcontroller, spi, serial

I am not able to communicate using SPI with between 2 devices. Below are oscilloscope plots.

I want to ask possible problems or errors that might have made in FW. I need to understand the general debug approach in this case.
[image]

Comment: Add a schematic. Why are the MISO and MOSi lines at such low amplitude. 10x probe? What is driving these lines. These seem to be in sync with the CS. Update your post with this info after you have received a few comments.

Comment: What's FW? And can we see a schematic?

Comment: "Nothing works what could be the problem"?  Answer: anything. Provide context and details. Schematics, source code, microcontroller type, datasheets, anything that might be relevant.

Comment: Elaborate "FW", elaborate your problem with circuit.

Answer (score 3):

A possible issue (if using a microcontroller for the SPI master) could be the MOSI and MISO pins are not programmed for SPI so it could be set to GPIO mode and output logic 0 by default. Or simply connected to wrong pins. It appears the CS and SCLK are working though. Try unplugging the MISO pin from the master to see if the slave device will toggle it, and if so then some other pin is keeping it low. Same for the MOSI pin, if connected to wrong pin on the slave.

Another possible issue is software related, so I suggest hard coding a single byte (such as 0x71) to be output to the MOSI and look for that bit pattern to understand the MSB/LSB direction. If using an interrupt routine, just hard code the output to this byte for the most simple debugging, then expand to a short known pattern, till you discover the issue.